# object oriented javascript - this [function] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am moving some jquery functions into a javascript object to clean up some code. My problem is, when I put methods on my object's constructor, calling `this.functionName()` returns the error `this.functionName is not a function` but if my functions are helper methods and are outside of the object's constructor, they work just fine.

Here is my code that does not work

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
    this.selectAllHandler();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
  var self = this;
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', function() {
        self.selectAllHandler.call(this);
    });
  },
  selectAllHandler: function() {
    // handler works fine
    var ids_array = this.idsArray(checkboxes); // error happening here
  },
  // helpers
  idsArray: function(checkboxes) {
    // trying to call
  }
}
```

But, having my object w/ a constructor and then calling the "helper" outside of the object works fine. For example, this works fine.

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', function() {
      self.selectAllHandler.call(this);
    });
  },
  selectAllHandler: function() {
    // handler works fine
    var ids_array = idsArray(checkboxes);
  }
}

function idsArray() {
  // code that works fine
}
```

One thing to note as well, is that in this scenario, by running console.log `this` refers to the element being clicked on, and not the constructor.

I have tried using `call`, `apply`, and `bind`, but have not had success, though I think it's been syntax related.

How can I build this so I can call my "helper" functions inside my object?

Comment: It's `self.selectAllHandler.call(self);`

Comment: Which can be simplified to just `self.selectAllHandler()`

Comment: or `$(document).on('click', '#my_element', this.selectAllHandler.bind(this));` or `$(document).on('click', '#my_element',e => this.selectAllHandler());`

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the answer. my event handler is not the problem (I just added that to show all my code I'm using). The problem i'm having is when i'm in the selectAllHandler trying to call my idsArray() function, is returning an error `this.idsArray is not a function`.

Comment: That event handler is precisely the problem. You're trying to call `selectAllHandler` with the context set as a `HTMLElement` (the `this` inside the event handler). Since `HTMLElement` does not have a function called `idsArray()`, it throws an error.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks for your help, but I was able to figure it out. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you were using `bind`, since you said it didn't work for you.
If you want, you can use bind like below. Also, in your code snippet `checkboxes` was not defined. This way you don't need to use `self`.

```js
function MyConstructor() {
  this.init();
  this.selectAllHandler();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    //var self = this;
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', function() {
      //self.selectAllHandler.call(self);
      this.selectAllHandler();
    }.bind(this));
  },
  selectAllHandler: function() {
    // handler works fine
    var checkboxes;
    var ids_array = this.idsArray(checkboxes); // error happening here
  },
  // helpers
  idsArray: function(checkboxes) {
    // trying to call
    console.log('test');
  }
}

var o = new MyConstructor();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. my event handler is not the problem (I just added that to show all my code I'm using). The problem i'm having is when i'm in the `selectAllHandler` trying to call my `idsArray()` function, is returning an error.

Comment: @JamesN The way I am calling bind will not cause an error in the `selectAllHandler` because `this` would be properly set. Did you try my code?

Comment: in refactoring my code, this is actually the solution I went with.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure it out. I thought I could call another function in the constructor just using `this.functionName()`. however, `$(this)` was referring to the element I was clicking on.

I remembered I defined `self (this)` in my init function which refers to the `window` object. Well, inside the `window` object is my object, and my function is on that object. So i was able to successfully call my object by doing

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.init();
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  init: function() {
  var self = this;
    $(document).on('click', '#my_element', function() {
        self.selectAllHandler.call(this);
    });
  },
  selectAllHandler: function() {
    // RIGHT HERE
    var ids_array = self.MyConstructor.prototype.idsArray(checkboxes);
  },
  // helpers
  idsArray: function(checkboxes) {
    // some codes
  }
}
```

Comment: To people stumbling upon this answer; this is not a good way of doing it. It is better to follow the examples in the comments or @Pankaj's answer

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the problem with your approach is how I structure my code using `$(this)`. By doing it your way, which there is obviously nothing wrong with it btw, `$(this)` no longer refers to the element i am clicking on and refers to my constructor. I use `($this)` pretty liberally in my constructor to check the state of the checkboxes I am clicking on.

Comment: If you want to do proper OOP, you shouldn't depend on `this` referring to anything other than the current instance of your object. If you want to keep track of the element you've clicked on, set an `element` property to that when you know what it is and use `$(this.element)` to get it. Doing it this way violates one of the central tenets of OOP; encapsulation. Your `selectAllHandler` knows too much about the environment in which it is running.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thank you for your insight. the next constructor i write I will remove instances of state like that.